# Adding other Android widgets into your app

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, launcher

I'm working on a program for android very similar to a car/media dock program but not quite. It will have shortcuts to launch apps, but I also want to add widgets to it.  I don't want this app to be a widget that the user can add to their homescreen.  I want the user to choose a widget they have installed and have that widget built into my dock program that fully functions....and that's where I hit a road bump that I can't figure out how to accomplish.

I tried looking through the launcher2 code but that's way more complex then what I need and I can't find any documentation for this function anywhere.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If it's "not a widget that the user can add to their homescreen", what kind of widget is it? Are you also providing custom widgets that you'll allow them to add, or is there some other form of widget?

Comment: for example if the user has Pandora installed, which contains a 4x1 widget.  I want my app to have the ability for the user to add that widget to my app's screen.

Comment: Your post states "Not a widget that the user can add to their homescreen." How is the Pandora widget not something users can add to their homescreen?

Comment: ah i see i left out a few words. edited up to make more sense, i hope. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen [this](http://coderender.blogspot.com/2012/01/hosting-android-widgets-my.html) AppWidgetHost tutorial?